# How to store path to a node in JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am working on a project where i want to create a series of Folders with structure and name similar to that of the JTree i have created.

To Simplify :

If A is the root node and B and C are its Children, in the backend, Folder with name "A" is created at the location "C:\Users\Sami\Desktop", Next both B and C are Created at "C:\Users\Sami\Desktop\A"

I am guessing that if i Traverse through each node and get their individual TreePath, it would  make things easier.

Is there any other alternative that I can go for?. If not how and where do i store the path to a particular node?

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

The following code, is a SSCCE (short self contained correct example). It transverses through all nodes in the tree and gets the path as a String. From there you can parse the Strings to your purpose.

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class StoreTreePathExample {
    public static void main(String[] args){     
    JTree tree = new JTree();
    Enumeration en = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getModel().getRoot()).preorderEnumeration();
      while(en.hasMoreElements()){
      TreePath path = new TreePath( ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)en.nextElement()).getPath() );
      String text = path.toString();
      System.out.println(text);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: nitpicking: that's _not_ a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), please look up what _self contained_ means